Is there an m such that for any i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2$... we have that $\frac{1}{n^m}(X_1 +...+X_n)$ converges to 0 in probability?
This is a question I found in one of my old probability exams. If the random variables have finite variance, this result seems easy by the law of large numbers. My intuition tells me its false for a non integrable r.v. like the one taking value $2^{n}$ with probability $2^{-n}$ (n a positive integer). However I don't know how to show this explicitly. I have not found a solution online or similar problems.
Thanks in advance for any help.

For almost sure convergence, the answer is no https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456394/can-a-non-integrable-random-variable-satisfy-a-strong-law-of-large-numbers-princ, can we use a similar argument?

Let $m>0$ be given (for $m\leq 0$ it is obviously wrong). For each $j\geq 1$, let $p_j=\frac{6}{\pi^2 j^2}$ (i. e. $\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j=1$). Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid discrete random variables taking values in $\{2,2^2,2^3,...\}$ with $P(X_i=2^j)=p_j$.
We'll now show that $\frac{1}{n^m}\sum_{j=1}^n X_i\not \to 0$ in probability. Let $\alpha>m$ and $j_n:=\lfloor \alpha \log_2(n^m)\rfloor$. Let's go for a Borel-Cantelli argument: Consider $B_n=\{X_n=2^{j_n}\}$, we then have:$$P(B_n)=p_{j_n}\approx \frac{6}{\pi^2(\alpha \log_2(n))^2},$$ but it is well known that $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log_2(n))^2}$ diverges. Since the $B_n$ are independent, we know by Borel-Cantelli that $P(B_n \text{ i. o.})=1$. Concrectly speaking, this means there are infinitely many $n$ such that $X_n=2^{j_n}$. For those $n$:$$\frac{X_n}{n^m}=\frac{2^{j_n}}{n^m}\approx n^{\alpha}/n^m=n^{\alpha-m}\to \infty$$ Now, since $\frac{X_1+\cdots +X_n}{n^m}\geq \frac{X_n}{n^m}$ it follows that $\frac{X_1+\cdots +X_n}{n^m}$ does not converge to $0$. In fact, it becomes aribitrarly large infinitely often.

EDIT: As Davide Giraudo pointed out, this only shows that it does not converge to $0$ almost surely.
Consider $A_n:=\{\text{at least one } X_1,..,X_n \text{ equals } 2^{j_n}\}$ We have $$P(A_n)=1-(1-p_{j_n})^n\approx 1-\exp[-np_{j_n}].$$ So, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=1$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, we then have:$$P\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n^m}>\varepsilon\right)\geq P(A_n)\to 1$$ So it can't converge to $0$ in probability aswell.

Thanks for pointing this out. You're absolutely right.

I think that now it is fine. Basically, you are showing that $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i/n^m$ does not converge to $0$ in probability. Maybe the argument could avoid some annoying steps like $1-(1-p_{j_n})^n\approx 1-\exp[-np_{j_n}]$ by choosing $X_1$ with values $2^{k\gamma},k\geq 1$, for some $\gamma$.

In fact, more is true: it is not possible to find a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers such that for each i.i.d. sequence $(X_i)$, $a_n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\to 0$ in probability.
Indeed, let  $(a_n)$  be an increasing sequence of positive  numbers, let $(X_i)$ be an i.i.d. sequence such that $n\mathbb P(X_1\geqslant a_n)\to 1$ (for example, $X_1$ takes the values $a_k$ with probability $1/k-1/(k+1)$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(S_n\geqslant a_n)\geqslant \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{X_i\geqslant a_n\}\right)=1-\left(1-\mathbb P(X_1\geqslant a_n)\right)^n=1-\left(1-\frac{n\mathbb P(X_1\geqslant a_n)}{n}\right)^n,
$$
hence $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(S_n\geqslant a_n)\geqslant 1-e^{-1}$.
